# Azure Repos Folder/Directory Comparison

Tags: git, azure-devops

We are starting to utilize the version control on Azure Devops with the Git Repos.
One topic that was asked is if there is a way to compare directories/branches/folders/repos on Azure Devops, say before deploying to a stage to see what chnages/differences are notable between the environments' directories before committing.

Is there such a tool/task built in that we can utilize? Perhaps BitBucket?

Basically, we are looking for something similar to BeyondCompare, the desktop file comprison tool, but for Directories comparison in Azure Devops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure DevOps has a [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1), which includes:

- a [Git REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)
- more accurately a [Git Diff API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/diffs?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

> Diffs compare a target version with a base version and return a list of items that are only in the target version. If either the target or base version isn't specified, then the default branch is used.

Since you are dealing with [Azure DevOps Git repositories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Frepos%2Fgit%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Frepos%2Fgit%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops), you can also clone it locally, and [review your history through Visual Studio or Command-line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/review-history?view=azure-devops&tabs=command-line).

Comment: yes, i think this is a good start, especially the git diff/branch comparison before a merge on web portal. Thanks :D

Comment: is it possible to do a git compare right in the azure-devops web interface ? the appeal of this over doing it in VS or another client-side tool is that then presumably I could send people a link to the diff. ie, [similar to GitHub](https://help.github.com/en/github/committing-changes-to-your-project/comparing-commits-across-time#comparing-commits).

Comment: @orionelenzil Not sure: I see local comparison (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/review-history?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio) but no web GUI.

Comment: thanks @VonC.  The web UI suggests it _might_ be possible because when viewing the changes for a particular commit it has text `Diff to Parent 1 - <my commit hash>` but I haven't figured out how to change `Parent 1`.  In any event, I realized my question might be more appropriate as [its own question, here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59533905/azure-devops-compare-two-commits-right-in-the-web-ui).